# $sce:itype error in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Could someone please explain with is $sce (dint quite understand the XSS security ) and how to solve the below error

```
error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: resourceUrl
```

This error only occurs when the JSON returned is multi dimension , when the JSON is multi dimensional i get the above even when the controllers.js in my app looks:

```
.controller('SearchCategoryControl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $sce) {
     var mycats = $stateParams.mycat
     $http.get('http://SRHRadio.com/podcasts/categories/'+mycats).success(funtion(data) {
     $scope.items = data;
     $scope.audioURL = $scope.items.resourceURI +   $scope.items.podcastfile
     $scope.audioURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.audioURL);         

});
```

resourceURI would be like http://127.0.0.1:80/Media and podcastfile : anil.mp3

Comment: Could you show the json that you have problem with?

Comment: can you show your html? $sce problems are usualy caused by binding HTML to your view from 'untrusted sources'

Comment: @OlivierRodomond , the below is the JSON :`[{"id":9,"title":"first test podcast","metadata":"test metadata for first audio","length":13.25,"dateofbroadcast":"2015-05-11T11:05:52+01:00","resourceURI":"http://127.0.0.1:80/Media/","podcastfile":"sumith.mp3","categories":"sports"}]` . The funny part is when the same JSON is without  [ ] it works fine

Comment: @StickyCube , my HTML to my view looks like `<ion-view view-title="Playlist by Search">
  <ion-content>
   <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="items in items">
       Title: {{items.title}} <br>
        Description: {{items.metadata}} <br>
        Length: {{items.length}} min <br>
        Category: <b>{{items.categories}} </b><br>
        Date of Broadcast: {{items.dateofbroadcast}} <br> <br> <audio  ng-hide="audioHide" controls ng-src="{{audioURL}}"></ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>` . Just to add i am using the ionic framework above the angular JS

Comment: been breaking my head and finally got it that the it was the array of JSON object that caused all the problem . As it was an array obviously `$scope.items = data;` dint make any sense and should have been `$scope.items = data[0];` and so the string `$scope.audioURL = $scope.items.resourceURI +   $scope.items.podcastfile` was being null

Answer (score 1):

Well i got the issue and so that in case in future someone else makes the same mistake i am answering my own question :

been breaking my head and finally got it that the it was the array of JSON object that caused all the problem . As it was an array obviously $scope.items = data; dint make any sense and should have been 
`$scope.items = data[0];` 
and so the string 
`scope.audioURL = $scope.items.resourceURI + $scope.items.podcastfile` was being null